# Rails 4: get data from many to many join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I did some research. Rails 3 use :select to inject the SQL to it, but deprecated in Rail 4.

How can I archive this easily?

For example in the following models.
I want

```
boss.employees[0].salary
```

Models

```
class Boss < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employments
    has_many :employees, :through => :employments
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employments
    has_many :bosses, :through => :employments
end
```

Employments Migration:

```
class CreateEmployments < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :employments do |t|
        t.integer :boss_id
        t.integer :employee_id
        t.decimal :salary

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Where does nurses come from?

Comment: @Dhaulagiri my bad, it should be employees

Comment: Please remember to read the helpful descriptions that pop up when adding tags to your question!

Comment: @Charles, what tags are appropriate for my question here?

Comment: @etlds, you used a typo tag that had a description telling people which tag to use instead.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found something.

```
class Boss < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :employees, -> { select('employees.*, employment.salary as salary') } :through => :employments
end
```

Comment: But there is another issue come up. When you try to call boss.employees.count, SQLException throw.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but I think you missed something. Your classes look fine, so does the Employment model. You did not post the Class Employment, so I am assuming it is the missing link in your system.

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :boss
    belongs_to :employee

end
```